# Combinations without Repetition

Tags: permutations, combinations

For calculating follow Combinations

```
RRDD
RDRD
RDDR
DRRD
DRDR
DDRR
```

answer is $\frac{4!}{(2!\times2!)}$.

First divide into $2!$ is because does not matter order of Rs or Ds (means we have not R1 and R2 or D1 and D2) {It's true?}. So what is the meaning of second $2!$ (Why divide it by $2!$ again)?

Or in another idea! first divide into $2!$ is because does not matter the order of Rs and next divide into 2! is because does not matter the order of Ds.

I'm completely confused! which idea is right?
It's Permutations or Combinations?

Answer (score 2):

The second idea is right. One $2!$ is because order of $R's$ don't matter and $2^{nd}$ for $D's$.

If you had $n$ $R's$ and $m$ $D's$, it would have been $\frac{(n+m)!}{n!m!}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please tell me It's Permutations or Combinations?

Comment: It's permutations. You can just google "permutations with repetitions" and you'd get some articles explaining about it.